# I cannot set the default of a drop downlist to the last item

Tags: javascript

I cannot set the default of a drop down list to the last item. If there is 3 items in the drop down list I want the third one to be the default for the drop down.
html where the drop down list is populated.

```
<div class='select'>
<select id='videoSource'></select>
</div>
```

javascript to open the camera and display avilable cameras on pc. Can some one please help me with this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
var videoSelect = document.querySelector("select#videoSource");
var startButton = document.querySelector("button#start");

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

function gotSources(sourceInfos) {
    for (var i = 0; i != sourceInfos.length; ++i) {
        var sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        var option = document.createElement("option"); 
        option.value = sourceInfo.id;
        if (sourceInfo.kind === 'video') {
            option.text = sourceInfo.label || 'camera ' + (videoSelect.length + 1);
            videoSelect.appendChild(option);                   
        } else {
            console.log('Some other kind of source: ', sourceInfo);
        }
    }
}

if (typeof MediaStreamTrack === 'undefined') {
    alert('This browser does not support MediaStreamTrack.\n\nTry Chrome Canary.');
} else {
    MediaStreamTrack.getSources(gotSources);
}


function successCallback(stream) {
    window.stream = stream; // make stream available to console
    videoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    videoElement.play();

  }

function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error);
}

function start() {
    if (!!window.stream) {
        videoElement.src = null;
        window.stream.stop();
    }

    var videoSource = videoSelect.value;
    var constraints = {
        video: {
            optional: [{ sourceId: videoSource}]
        }
    };
    navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
}


videoSelect.onchange = start;

start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *last option* set the **`selected`** attribute to **`true`** within the *for* loop.

```
if( i == sourceInfos.length - 1 ) {
    option.selected = true;
}
```

Comment: It's possible that the last element in the sourceInfos does not have kind=='video' in which case it wouldn't appear in the select list.

Comment: @isick maybe.  But to be exact about `last option`, then the above is the wise solution.  Also using `selected` attribute only we can know the default element.  Hope you understand.

Comment: I understand your preference to use the selected attribute, but your algorithm for finding the last option is inadequate. It's important that other people attempting to implement your solution understand it has obvious (and avoidable) fail cases.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be after you append the new option in the gotSources function, to add

```
videoSelect.value = sourceInfo.id;
```

so it would read

```
    if (sourceInfo.kind === 'video') {
        option.text = sourceInfo.label || 'camera ' + (videoSelect.length + 1);
        videoSelect.appendChild(option);                   
        videoSelect.value = sourceInfo.id; //update the value to the last element
    } else {
        console.log('Some other kind of source: ', sourceInfo);
    }
```

That will set it for every new option added (not the most "efficient" solution, but definitely wont experience in decrease in performance). If you want to issue the value set command exactly once you'll need to store the the last option added and set it outside the for loop.

Again, probably not worth it, but your call.